How to implicitly infer generic types from interface property value
So, I have this interface for my Express controller handler.
interface Handler<
  Body extends ZodObject,
  Query extends ZodObject,
  Params extends ZodObject,
> {
  path?: string;
  method: "get" | "post" | "put" | "patch" | "delete";
  validators?: {
    body?: Body;
  };
  handler: RequestHandler<z.infer<Body>>;
}

What I want is that the type of Body should be inferred from the object I set at validator.body. Let's say I set it to z.object({ x: z.string() }), then I want to the req parameter of handler function to have req.body as { x: string }, but I can't make it happen.
I tried searching for it on Google and even tried GPT and Gemini but none can solve this problem. I just want to know whether this can be done or not, and if yes then how.

Try ChatGPT 4o - it had something to say ;)

From this post I came to know that what I am trying to achieve is not possible. So I settled with another approach:
interface Handler<
  B extends ZodObject = ZodObject,
  P extends ZodObject = ZodObject,
  Q extends ZodObject = ZodObject,
> {
  path?: string;
  method: "get" | "post" | "put" | "patch" | "delete";
  validators?: {
    body?: B;
    query?: Q;
    params?: P;
  };
  handler: RequestHandler<z.infer<P>, any, z.infer<B>, z.infer<Q>>;
}

interface Controller {
  handlers: Handler[];
  registerHandler: <B, P, Q>(handler: Handler<B, P, Q>) => void;
}

